# How to Get Rid of GPT-2 Warning Message?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, gpt-2

Every time I run GPT-2, I am receiving this message. Is there a way I can get this to go away?

```
Some weights of GPT2LMHeadModel were not initialized from the model checkpoint at gpt2 and are newly initialized: ['h.0.attn.masked_bias', 'h.1.attn.masked_bias', 'h.2.attn.masked_bias', 'h.3.attn.masked_bias', 'h.4.attn.masked_bias', 'h.5.attn.masked_bias', 'h.6.attn.masked_bias', 'h.7.attn.masked_bias', 'h.8.attn.masked_bias', 'h.9.attn.masked_bias', 'h.10.attn.masked_bias', 'h.11.attn.masked_bias', 'lm_head.weight']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
```

Comment: Please provide your [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to change the [loglevel](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#levels) **before you import anything** from the transformers library:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level='ERROR')

from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel

model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2')
```